# Django models relationships - the most efficient way to create\update and save

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry for the newbie question.
Im wondering what is the most efficient way to save multiple relationship models to the database.
Lets say I got 3 models with relationships:

```
class ModelA(BaseModel):
    some_field = models.BooleanField()
```

```
class ModelB(BaseModel):
    some_field = models.BooleanField()
    relation = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="modelB", null=True, blank=True)
```

```
class ModelC(BaseModel):
    some_field = models.BooleanField()
    relation = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modelC')
```

And I'm creating new `ModelA` in the database, and I want to save `ModelB` and `ModelC` as relationships.

```
model_a = ModelA.objects.create(some_field=True)
model_b = ModelB(some_field=True, relation= model_a)
model_c1 = ModelC(some_field=True, relation= model_a)
model_c2 = ModelC(some_field=True, relation= model_a)

model_a.save() //<--This won't save model_b and c models to the to the DB
```

I looking for more efficient way to save model_an instead of saving after each relationship creation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create related objects, when saving `model_a`, you can do it in the `save` method of `ModelA`:

```py
class ModelA(BaseModel):
    some_field = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        model_b = ModelB.objects.create(some_field=True, relation=self)
        model_c = ModelC.objects.create(some_field=True, relation=self)
```

In this way, when you call `model_a.save()`, `model_b` and `model_c` would be created.

Comment: Thanks @Amin, not sure in a real world scenario save function will have all the parameters I need to create other models, but I wonder, is this way more efficient? or just cleaner?

Comment: @ItayAmza It's just cleaner and helps you avoid calling `save` on related models. If you want to create all objects in just one query, I don't think there would be such a thing.

Comment: so saving each model separately is a good practice?